# Question regarding the Doppler Effect in a binary star system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, doppler-effect

I was studying Doppler effect and could not understand the effect of Doppler effect in the following systems.

[image]

In the above system the book says the doppler shift is zero

[image]

However in this system there is a doppler shift.

I mainly studied the doppler effect where there two objects but here here there are three bodies(two stars and Earth) so I could not understand why the doppler shift is zero for the first case.

So could anyone please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In picture 1 none of the 2 stars has a component of motion in direction to earth,
in the second picture they may move in different directions one to one against earth, or both in one direction but with different velocities .
(This movement is added to the velocity the system has against earth)

Comment: Ahk, the doppler effect is only felt when a "Component"  of the velocity is in the direction of motion of the other object. Right?